# xuggler InputOutputStreamHandler SIGSEGV

Tags: java, xuggler

I'm trying to run an example of InputOutputStreamHandler of xuggler. I'm trying to convert a video to FLV and write the resulting video to standard output. Here's the source code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.io.InputOutputStreamHandler;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.io.XugglerIO;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        OutputStream outStream = System.out;
        InputOutputStreamHandler handler = new InputOutputStreamHandler(outStream);

        IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("myvideo.flv");
        IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(XugglerIO.map(XugglerIO
            .generateUniqueName(handler, ".flv"), handler), reader);
        reader.addListener(writer);
        while(reader.readPacket() == null);
    }
 }
```

My problem is that when I try to run this program, it crashes and I get the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3ed28442e8, pid=9103, tid=139908218222336
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64     compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle5976644928112967115.tmp+0x2f02e8]  avio_write+0x18
...
```

File hs_err_pid.log mentions:

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.IContainer_writeHeader(JLcom/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer;)I+0
j  com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.writeHeader()I+5
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.getStream(I)Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IStream;+222
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeAudio(ILcom/xuggle/xuggler/IAudioSamples;)V+17
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onAudioSamples(Lcom/xuggle/mediatool/event/IAudioSamplesEvent;)V+16
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onAudioSamples(Lcom/xuggle/mediatool/event/IAudioSamplesEvent;)V+31
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchAudioSamples(ILcom/xuggle/xuggler/IAudioSamples;)V+14
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeAudio(Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IStreamCoder;Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IPacket;)V+91
j  com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket()Lcom/xuggle/xuggler/IError;+131
j  Test.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+45
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Does anyone know how can I bypass this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just a quick update, this seems to be a bug of Xuggler 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're trying to convert a video to flv, but your input file is already a flv file - `myvideo.flv`. Is that correct?

Also, have you tried simplifying the `makeWriter` call so that it's just using a hardcoded filename? So it becomes something like this:

```
IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter("output.flv", reader);
```

I'm curious whether the whole process of generating a unique filename on top of the `System.out` streamhandler might have something to do with the problem. Maybe add some code to log the filename that's generated.

```
String filename = XugglerIO.map(XugglerIO.generateUniqueName(handler, ".flv"),
  handler);
System.out.println(filename);
```

**Update**

Some other suggestions you could try to narrow down the problem:

1. Create your own `OutputStream` class that does nothing more than log the calls made to it so you can get a better idea of where the code is failing. Does it fail immediately before even trying to write something or does it get to a certain point before it dies.
2. If that doesn't get you anywhere, try creating your own [`IURLProtocolHandler`](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/io/IURLProtocolHandler.java) class which does nothing but log calls. See if perhaps you're getting calls that an `OutputStream` wouldn't be able to handle, like `seek` for example.

It might just be that xuggler can't output certain formats to a stream. For example, if a FLV header is something that needs to be written to the beginning of the file, but the details that are needed in the header are only known once everything else has been written (e.g. file size), it would require an output handler that was capable of seeking back to the beginning of the file. You obviously can't do that with a stream.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. The input video is not a problem, I've tried with mp4, avi and other formats and got the same problem. I tried using the simple writer, and it writes the file to the output. My objective is to write the transcoded video to an output stream instead of a file. System.out was an example, I had the same problem with ByteArrayOutputStream or PipedOutputStream.

Comment: I've added some other suggestions you could try to my answer. But I suspect the problem is that xuggler can't output a flv to a stream because of the way the file format is structured.